# Firefox extension: download and unpack ZIP

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

How can I download and unpack ZIP file to extension folder?
Need to update my resources/config from ZIP package stored online.

Is this possible?

Please point me over to documentation or examples

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox 4+ you can get the directory of your extension like this:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
AddonManager.getAddonByID(extensionID, function(addon) {
  var extensionDir =
    Services.io.getProtocolHandler("file").QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileProtocolHandler).
      getFileFromURLSpec(addon.getResourceURI(null).spec);
}
```

To download the file from an extension, create an XMLHttpRequest using:

```
var xhr = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpReques‌​t);
```

You can read the ZIP file using the nsIZipReader XPCOM interface (see http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/modules/libjar/nsIZipReader.idl). Instantiate the component like this:

```
var zipReader = Cc["@mozilla.org/libjar/zip-reader;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIZipReader);
```

Comment: thanks, and download the ZIP to that directory via what call, please? or to any directory where it will persist cleaning browser cache?

Comment: Are you asking how to download the ZIP file from your server or how to unzip it?

Comment: how to download it via extension, unzip is done via extract call http://doxygen.db48x.net/mozilla/html/interfacensIZipReader.html#a1cd08bee10ca99cdff3187d8b842012f

Comment: Create an XMLHttpRequest using `var xhr = Cc["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIXMLHttpRequest);`. You can then use it like any normal XMLHttpRequest to download the file.